# How to paint on wallpaper above icons? Alternative to progman 0x052C

Tags: c++, windows, hwnd, windows-desktop-gadgets

I created a simple windows app that i want to pin to my desktop similar to a wallpaper widget. I am using a nodeJS module that is almost doing everything i want. Essentially from my limited understanding this module is utlizing windows libraries and its creating a `progman` worker and sending the `0x052C` instruction to create a Window on the desktops wallpaper plane.

I think its defining the type of window and its position (wallpaper) based on this value? `0x052C`

```
 // Message to Progman to spawn a WorkerW
    static int WM_SPAWN_WORKER = 0x052C;
```

The app is built with Electron which is NodeJS enviroment so im a bit ignorant in the world of C++ and C#. But i have 2 issues right now with my window.

**Issue #1:** My window doesnt allow any mouse interaction. I can not push any of the buttons in my app for example. I assume this is because its on the desktop wallpaper plane.

**Issue #2:** My window is allowing my desktop icons above it. Which makes sense. But I wanted to find a way to make them on the wallpaper but not behind the icons. *But behind every other window*.

**Question 1:** where can i learn about this value and possible other value's I can send to progman? `0x052C` or am i misunderstanding?

**Question 2:** how can i draw above the desktops wallpaper but under all normal windows? Is there a tutorial i can follow to learn how to achieve this and solve *Issue #1* and *Issue #2*?

A big reason i used this method was to avoid getting my window hidden from the "show desktop" feature in windows. Trying to get my window to behave like a desktop gadget.

I just need a starting point or a spark to find the correct library/instructions to use. Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Where did you get 0x052C from? Progman does not have a documented API that lets you do this.

Comment: Just google 0x052C. Its clear what it does.